# How can I populate my sql database with data from a variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a Phone Gap app and I'm trying to use the sql Phone Gap database to store JSON data. I have no idea of how to store the JSON information which will be stored in a variable. Everything works fine but I have no idea how to populate the database with the variable information from JSON. Here's the code:

This is the part of the code below I'm having trouble with:

```
// Populate the database
//
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}
```

Where "First row" is, I'd it there to be the variable which will store the JSON data. I have no idea how to place a variable there and have it understood as a variable containing info. How can I populate the database with information I want from a variable?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Storage Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

// Populate the database
//
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

// Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(tx, err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Example</h1>
<p>Database</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing where your json variable is coming from... Can only say that you can insert the variable into the SQL statement using concatenation.

```
// Populate the database
//
var JSONvar = "json string";
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "'+ JSONvar +'")');
}
```

Since global variables are generally taboo, you might want to wrap the call to `populateDB` in an anonymous function and pass it the json you want to use.

```
// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var json = '["a", "json", "string"]';
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(function(tx){ populateDB(tx, json); }, errorCB, successCB);
}

// Populate the database
//
function populateDB(tx, JSONvar) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "'+ JSONvar +'")');
}
```

Comment: I receive:
Error processing SQL!
Error code 5; message: could not prepare
statement (1 no such column: hello)

hello is the string I stored in JSONvar

Comment: Sorry yeah, I forgot to wrap the json in quotes to treat it as a string instead of a column name ;)  Should work now.